# nested class or struct in a class

Tags: c++, nested-class

Code goes first:

//.h file

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        B makeB(int);  //question 1
    //protected:
        struct B {
            int _id;
            B(int id);
        }
};
```

//.cpp file

```
A::A()
{  cout<<"A ctor\n"; }

B A::makeB(int id)  //question 2
{  return B(id); }
```

2 questions:

1.Should I put makeB() function after the definition of struct B?

2.In .cpp file, should prefix every B with A:: ?

**PS:**
1.If makeB function doesn't deal with B instances, but B pointers or refs, can I put a forward decl of struct B in front of makeB? (I just don't want put the definition of struct B in front of mem-funcs).

Comment: you make B available as public (makeB), but B is defined as protected..?

Comment: @duedl0r, sorry, edited.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title, but in the "tags" next time.

Comment: @WTP, got it, I won't do that next time.

Comment: "I just don't want put the definition of struct B in front of mem-funcs" Why? If you are exposing  `B` in the public interface of your class (through `makeB`), it makes all the sense to let users know `B`'s declaration in advance.

Comment: @Antonio, well that's right, probably that's just my weird personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles fine:

```
class A
{
 public:
    struct B;

    A();
    B makeB(int);  //question 1

    struct B {
        int _id;
        B(int id) {};
    };
};

A::A() {}

A::B A::makeB(int id)  //question 2
{  return B(id); }
```

Comment: anyway, I gotta prefix B with A:: if the member function is not implement inside the class body, right?

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Yes (it needs to know the size of struct B)

QPS1. Yes (if it only uses pointers to B, it does not need to know the size)

Q2. Also, you can write "using A::B" and then, use "B" as usual.

Comment: Q1: In c++03 a declaration that is not a definition does *not* need to know the size of the return type or arguments (in C++11 the wording is completely unclear to me, but I would expect the rules to be backward compatible). Q2: It seems to me that either A would have to be a namespace name, or this using declaration goes into the class and then A would have to be a base class of B. Can you show a compilable example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes. Otherwise, this should be hard to compile.

Comment: but can I get around this by adding a declaration of struct B in front of makeB?

Comment: @Luchian, if I am using a pointer or reference, then Can I put a forward decl in front of makeB?

Comment: @Alcott: see my answer using forward decl.